# how to append different return values in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a function something like:

```
def function(self):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(10):
        contents = [1,0,1,0] #integer values in a list, changes every time when running function()
        matrix .append(contents)
    self.matrix = matrix 
    return matrix
```

and I have another empty list, what I’m trying to do is to append `matrix` into `empty_matrix` 5 times,
So the result should be like:

```
empty_matrix = [[matrix1],[matrix2],[matrix3],[matrix4],[matrix5]]
```

But I’m not sure how to make Matrix1,2,3,4,5 have different values. When I run `function(self)` alone it returns different value, but when I append it into empty_matrix, it appends the same value, like

```
empty_matrix = [[matrix1],[matrix1],[matrix1],[matrix1],[matrix1]].
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Original code is attached below:

```
def generate_population(self):
    model = self.model
    weights_origin = model.get_weights()
    shape_list = []
    matrix= []
    empty_matrix= [[],[],[],[],[]]


    for i, w in enumerate(weights_origin):
        #get shape of w -> save shape into shape_list -> generate binary_value that has the shape of shape_list 
        #-> convert binary_value to float32 -> define it as tf Variable -> append to rand_covers list
        w_shape = tf.shape(w)
        shape_list.append(w_shape)
        binary_value = np.random.randint(2, size = shape_list[i])      
        to_float = tf.cast(binary_value, tf.float32)  
        weights2 = tf.Variable(to_float, name="addition_"+str(i), trainable=True)
        matrix.append(weights2)

    for j in range(5):
        empty_matrix[j].append(matrix)


self.matrix = matrix
return matrix
```

Comment: Could you please add the entire code, so that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: how you adding the matrix to `empty_matrix`

Comment: why do you run only append() in `for j in range(5):` ? This way you add the same matrix 5 time. Insite this `for`-loor you have to run your function which generate new matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
for j in range(5):
    empty_matrix[j].append(matrix)
```

you need

```
for j in range(5):
    matrix = function()
    empty_matrix[j].append(matrix)
```

---

If you want to use the same matrix at start and later change values in one of them without changing values in others then you have to duplicate them using `.copy()`

```
matrix = function()

for j in range(5):
    empty_matrix[j].append( matrix.copy() )
```

or `copy.deepcopy()` for deep duplication

```
import copy

matrix = function()

for j in range(5):
    empty_matrix[j].append( copy.deepcopy(matrix.copy) )
```

---

**EDIT:**

I don't understand what you try to do but code seems strange and I would write it

```
def generate_population(self):
    model = self.model
    weights_origin = model.get_weights()
    shape_list = []

    empty_matrix= [[],[],[],[],[]]

    for j in range(5):

        matrix = []

        for i, w in enumerate(weights_origin):
            #get shape of w -> save shape into shape_list -> generate binary_value that has the shape of shape_list 
            #-> convert binary_value to float32 -> define it as tf Variable -> append to rand_covers list
            w_shape = tf.shape(w)
            shape_list.append(w_shape)
            binary_value = np.random.randint(2, size = shape_list[i])      
            to_float = tf.cast(binary_value, tf.float32)  
            weights2 = tf.Variable(to_float, name="addition_"+str(i), trainable=True)
            matrix.append(weights2)

        empty_matrix[j].append(matrix)

    return empty_matrix

# --- outside function ---

empty_matrix = generate_population()
```

or

```
def generate_population(self):
    model = self.model
    weights_origin = model.get_weights()
    shape_list = []

    matrix = []

    for i, w in enumerate(weights_origin):
        #get shape of w -> save shape into shape_list -> generate binary_value that has the shape of shape_list 
        #-> convert binary_value to float32 -> define it as tf Variable -> append to rand_covers list
        w_shape = tf.shape(w)
        shape_list.append(w_shape)
        binary_value = np.random.randint(2, size=shape_list[i])      
        to_float = tf.cast(binary_value, tf.float32)  
        weights2 = tf.Variable(to_float, name="addition_"+str(i), trainable=True)
        matrix.append(weights2)

    return matrix

# --- outside function ---

empty_matrix= [[],[],[],[],[]]

for j in range(5):
    matrix = generate_population()
    empty_matrix[j].append(matrix)
```

Comment: Hi, Could you explain how matrix = function() works? I followed your instruction but it says "name ''function" is not defined

Comment: I don't understand - in question you show `def function()` and it `return matrix` and this gives you this matrix when you run `matrix = function()`

Comment: if you don't have `function()` then in place of `matrix = function()` you have to run code which generate new matrix.

Comment: sorry, still don't get it. I don't think matrix = generate_population() works in main function and generate_population itself. I guess I'm missing something..

Comment: I don't know what exactly you try to generate in function - one matrix or list of matrix (empty_matrix) but I would write it in different way. See new code in answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!